# How to stop Big Query using old schema when creating new table with the same name as a deleted one from Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery, schema

I am using a Google Sheet as the source of a table in Big Query.  Since I am unable to rename fieldnames in the schema of an existing table I deleted the table and attempted to re-create it after amending the column names in the source Google Sheet.  I need to keep the table name the same as I already have analysis files connecting to the table, however when I create the new table as ask Big Query to auto-detect the schema it uses the schema of the previous table.  Even if I enter the new schema as text when creating the table it ignores what I enter and use the schema from the old table.

Any ideas how I get Big Query to detect the new schema from the Google Sheet whilst using the same table name as the deleted table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After trying this multiple times and it not working - with several tables - randomly it worked and let me create a table with the new scheme (manually).  Not sure why this didn't work before as I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything differently.  If anyone has any insight on what might have caused the initial errors I'd love to hear it for future reference but my current problem is solved.